# Can't connect with URL connection

Tags: java, url, connection

I am trying to connect to a website where the site database adds a name to a list based on the url you connect with. I can't connect. The site works and I can access it in a browser. The error is an IOException.

```
if ((Boolean) value)
                {
                    System.out.println("setValue");
                    try 
                    {
                        URL myURL = new URL("http://app.bannervision.tv/api/add/" + data.name.get(row));
                        URLConnection myURLConnection = myURL.openConnection();
                        myURLConnection.connect();
                    } 
                    catch (MalformedURLException e) 
                    { 
                        System.out.println("MalformedURLException");
// ...
                    } 
                    catch (IOException e) 
                    {   
                        System.out.println("IOException");
                        System.out.println("http://app.bannervision.tv/api/add/" + data.name.get(row));
// openConnection() failed
// ...
                    }
                }
```

Comment: Print the stack trace. Don't catch and print your own stuff

Comment: in addition to the above comment, print the final value in the url construction and see if it is the correct way to call the website. print the value of this: "http://app.bannervision.tv/api/add/" + data.name.get(row)

Comment: then take whatever it prints and try it in your browser and see if it works

Comment: A quick google of the base url looks like there is user authentication needed. If this is true you will have to submit user credentials to the url